# How to highlight multiline text on a QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to highlight multiline comments on a `QTextEdit`, I searched around for how this is done on Qt Designer (in the `QTextEdit` when you are editing a `stylesheet` multiline comments are highlighted)

I found a class named `HtmlHighlighter` at `msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qsyntaxhighlighter.h` (not sure if this is the correct class used by Designer)

when I set it on the first `QTextEdit` of the `QMainWindow` nothing is highlighted, I'm missing something?

Based on the `HtmlHighlighter` class, I have written the `MyHtmlHighlighter` class, the problem is it only highlights comments that are on the same line:

[image]

How i could get multiline comments highlighted in a `QTextEdit`?

```
#include "htmlhighlighter.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    QList<QTextEdit*> textEditList = w.findChildren<QTextEdit*>();

    HtmlHighlighter* highlighter = new HtmlHighlighter(textEditList[0]);
    MyHtmlHighlighter* highlighter_2 = new MyHtmlHighlighter(textEditList[1]);
    return a.exec();
}
```

`mainwindow`

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) , ui(new Ui::MainWindow())
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QString text = QString(R"(/*abc*/ 
/* 
abc
 */
)");
    QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    QTextEdit* textEdit_2 = new QTextEdit(this);
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(ui->centralWidget);
    layout->addWidget(textEdit);
    layout->addWidget(textEdit_2);

    textEdit->setText(text);
    textEdit_2->setText(text);
}
```

`htmlhighlighter`

```
class MyHtmlHighlighter : public QSyntaxHighlighter
{
public:
    MyHtmlHighlighter(QWidget* parent) : QSyntaxHighlighter(parent)
    {
        commentFormat.setForeground(QColor("#29ff3d"));
        commentFormat.setFontItalic(true);
        highlightingRules.append({QRegularExpression("/\\*(.|\\n)*?\\*/"), commentFormat});
    };

protected:
    void highlightBlock(const QString& text) override
    {
        for (const HighlightingRule& rule : highlightingRules)
        {
            QRegularExpressionMatchIterator matchIterator = rule.pattern.globalMatch(text);

            while (matchIterator.hasNext())
            {
                QRegularExpressionMatch match = matchIterator.next();
                setFormat(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), rule.format);
            }
        }
    }

private:
    struct HighlightingRule
    {
        QRegularExpression pattern;
        QTextCharFormat format;
    };
    QList<HighlightingRule> highlightingRules;
    QTextCharFormat commentFormat;
};


// extracted from: msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qsyntaxhighlighter.h
using namespace Qt::StringLiterals;

class HtmlHighlighter : public QSyntaxHighlighter
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum Construct
    {
        Entity,
        Tag,
        Comment,
        Attribute,
        Value,
        LastConstruct = Value
    };

    HtmlHighlighter(QTextEdit* textEdit) : QSyntaxHighlighter(textEdit->document())
    {
        QTextCharFormat entityFormat;
        entityFormat.setForeground(Qt::red);
        setFormatFor(Entity, entityFormat);

        QTextCharFormat tagFormat;
        tagFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkMagenta);
        tagFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
        setFormatFor(Tag, tagFormat);

        QTextCharFormat commentFormat;
        commentFormat.setForeground(Qt::gray);
        commentFormat.setFontItalic(true);
        setFormatFor(Comment, commentFormat);

        QTextCharFormat attributeFormat;
        attributeFormat.setForeground(Qt::black);
        attributeFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
        setFormatFor(Attribute, attributeFormat);

        QTextCharFormat valueFormat;
        valueFormat.setForeground(Qt::blue);
        setFormatFor(Value, valueFormat);
    }

    void setFormatFor(Construct construct, const QTextCharFormat& format)
    {
        m_formats[construct] = format;
        rehighlight();
    }

    QTextCharFormat formatFor(Construct construct) const
    {
        return m_formats[construct];
    }

protected:
    enum State
    {
        NormalState = -1,
        InComment,
        InTag
    };

    void highlightBlock(const QString& text) override
    {
        static const QChar tab = u'\t';
        static const QChar space = u' ';

        int state = previousBlockState();
        qsizetype len = text.size();
        qsizetype start = 0;
        qsizetype pos = 0;

        while (pos < len) {
            switch (state) {
            case NormalState:
            default:
            while (pos < len) {
                QChar ch = text.at(pos);
                if (ch == u'<') {
                    if (QStringView{text}.sliced(pos).startsWith("<!--"_L1)) {
                        state = InComment;
                    }
                    else {
                        state = InTag;
                        start = pos;
                        while (pos < len && text.at(pos) != space
                            && text.at(pos) != u'>'
                            && text.at(pos) != tab
                            && !QStringView{text}.sliced(pos).startsWith("/>"_L1)) {
                            ++pos;
                        }
                        if (QStringView{text}.sliced(pos).startsWith("/>"_L1))
                            ++pos;
                        setFormat(start, pos - start,
                            m_formats[Tag]);
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if (ch == u'&') {
                    start = pos;
                    while (pos < len && text.at(pos++) != u';')
                        ;
                    setFormat(start, pos - start,
                        m_formats[Entity]);
                }
                else {
                    // No tag, comment or entity started, continue...
                    ++pos;
                }
            }
            break;
            case InComment:
            start = pos;
            for (; pos < len; ++pos) {
                if (QStringView{text}.sliced(pos).startsWith("-->"_L1)) {
                    pos += 3;
                    state = NormalState;
                    break;
                }
            }
            setFormat(start, pos - start, m_formats[Comment]);
            break;
            case InTag:
            QChar quote = QChar::Null;
            while (pos < len) {
                QChar ch = text.at(pos);
                if (quote.isNull()) {
                    start = pos;
                    if (ch == '\''_L1 || ch == u'"') {
                        quote = ch;
                    }
                    else if (ch == u'>') {
                        ++pos;
                        setFormat(start, pos - start, m_formats[Tag]);
                        state = NormalState;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (QStringView{text}.sliced(pos).startsWith("/>"_L1)) {
                        pos += 2;
                        setFormat(start, pos - start, m_formats[Tag]);
                        state = NormalState;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (ch != space && text.at(pos) != tab) {
                        // Tag not ending, not a quote and no whitespace, so
                        // we must be dealing with an attribute.
                        ++pos;
                        while (pos < len && text.at(pos) != space
                            && text.at(pos) != tab
                            && text.at(pos) != u'=')
                            ++pos;
                        setFormat(start, pos - start, m_formats[Attribute]);
                        start = pos;
                    }
                }
                else if (ch == quote) {
                    quote = QChar::Null;

                    // Anything quoted is a value
                    setFormat(start, pos - start, m_formats[Value]);
                }
                ++pos;
            }
            break;
            }
        }
        setCurrentBlockState(state);
    }

private:
    QTextCharFormat m_formats[LastConstruct + 1];
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very good and detailed [Syntax Highlighter Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-richtext-syntaxhighlighter-example.html) in the Qt Documentation, with a section that explains how to deal with multiline comments explained in [Highlighter class implementation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-richtext-syntaxhighlighter-example.html#highlighter-class-implementation) section.

Here's my own extraction of it:

> the multiline comment needs special care due to the design of the [QSyntaxHighlighter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) class.
>
> After a [QSyntaxHighlighter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) object is created, its [highlightBlock()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#highlightBlock) function will be called automatically whenever it is necessary by the rich text engine, highlighting the given text block. The problem appears when a comment spans several text blocks. We will take a closer look at how this problem can be solved when reviewing the implementation of the Highlighter::highlightBlock() function. At this point we only specify the multiline comment's color.
>
> ```
> setCurrentBlockState(0);
> ```
>
> To deal with constructs that can span several text blocks (like the C++ multiline comment), it is necessary to know the end state of the previous text block (e.g. "in comment"). Inside your highlightBlock() implementation you can query the end state of the previous text block using the [QSyntaxHighlighter::previousBlockState()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#previousBlockState) function. After parsing the block you can save the last state using [QSyntaxHighlighter::setCurrentBlockState()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#setCurrentBlockState).
>
> The [previousBlockState()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#previousBlockState) function return an int value. If no state is set, the returned value is -1. You can designate any other value to identify any given state using the [setCurrentBlockState()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#setCurrentBlockState) function. Once the state is set, the [QTextBlock](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextblock.html) keeps that value until it is set again or until the corresponding paragraph of text is deleted.
>
> In this example we have chosen to use 0 to represent the "not in comment" state, and 1 for the "in comment" state. When the stored syntax highlighting rules are applied we initialize the current block state to 0.
>
> ```
> int startIndex = 0;
> if (previousBlockState() != 1)
>    startIndex = text.indexOf(commentStartExpression);
> ```
>
> If the previous block state was "in comment" (previousBlockState() == 1), we start the search for an end expression at the beginning of the text block. If the previousBlockState() returns 0, we start the search at the location of the first occurrence of a start expression.
>
> ```
> while (startIndex >= 0) {
>     QRegularExpressionMatch match = commentEndExpression.match(text, startIndex);
>     int endIndex = match.capturedStart();
>     int commentLength = 0;
>     if (endIndex == -1) {
>        setCurrentBlockState(1);
>        commentLength = text.length() - startIndex;
>     } else {
>        commentLength = endIndex - startIndex
>                           + match.capturedLength();
>     }
>     setFormat(startIndex, commentLength, multiLineCommentFormat);
>     startIndex = text.indexOf(commentStartExpression, startIndex + commentLength);
> }
> ```
>
> When an end expression is found, we calculate the length of the comment and apply the multiline comment format. Then we search for the next occurrence of the start expression and repeat the process. If no end expression can be found in the current text block we set the current block state to 1, i.e. "in comment".

**TL;DR:** [QSyntaxHighlighter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) only formats one text block at a time, a multiline comment is formed of several ones, hence why you are only able to format single line comments.

Based on that, I changed `MyHtmlHighlighter` as follows:

```
class MyHtmlHighlighter : public QSyntaxHighlighter
{
public:
    MyHtmlHighlighter(QWidget* parent) : QSyntaxHighlighter(parent)
    {
        commentFormat.setForeground(QColor("#29ff3d"));
        commentFormat.setFontItalic(true);
        commentStartExpression = QRegularExpression(QStringLiteral("/\\*"));
        commentEndExpression = QRegularExpression(QStringLiteral("\\*/"));
    }

protected:
    void highlightBlock(const QString& text) override
    {
        //useless for multiline comment formatting
        for (const HighlightingRule& rule : highlightingRules)
        {
            QRegularExpressionMatchIterator matchIterator = rule.pattern.globalMatch(text);

            while (matchIterator.hasNext())
            {
                QRegularExpressionMatch match = matchIterator.next();
                setFormat(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), rule.format);
            }
        }

        //this is where multiline comments processing starts
        setCurrentBlockState(0);

        int startIndex = 0;
        if (previousBlockState() != 1)
            startIndex = text.indexOf(commentStartExpression);

        while (startIndex >= 0)
        {
            QRegularExpressionMatch match = commentEndExpression.match(text, startIndex);
            int endIndex = match.capturedStart();
            int commentLength = 0;

            if (endIndex == -1)
            {
                setCurrentBlockState(1);
                commentLength = text.length() - startIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                commentLength = endIndex - startIndex
                                + match.capturedLength();
            }

            setFormat(startIndex, commentLength, commentFormat);
            startIndex = text.indexOf(commentStartExpression, startIndex + commentLength);
        }
    }

private:
    struct HighlightingRule
    {
        QRegularExpression pattern;
        QTextCharFormat format;
    };
    QList<HighlightingRule> highlightingRules;
    QTextCharFormat commentFormat;
    //added
    QRegularExpression commentStartExpression;
    QRegularExpression commentEndExpression;
};
```

Here's a test:

[image: multiline formatting]